# Undefined function or variable in Matlab when calling a function from cmd

Tags: matlab, cmd

I have a function in Matlab like this:

```
function func(v1)
v1
end
```

and I want to call it from cmd.
so when I call it in cmd with command like

`matlab -nodisplay -r "func("hello");"`

I face an error:

> Undefined function or variable 'hello'.

but I just want to have string "hello" in my function.

when I try a function which has not any argument, it works properly. but the error occurs when I want to pass argument to the function.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use single quotes here:

```
matlab -nodisplay -r "func('hello');"
```

Comment: when I want to call the function from another directory, I use command like
>matlab -r "D:/matlab_function/func('hello');"
and I get the error  --> Error: Invalid use of operator. how should I set the command here

Comment: @ali Don't do that, use the `sd` flag to change directory

Comment: could you please elaborate on your explanation. did you mean cd or sd

Comment: I meant `sd`. See https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabwindows.html